# How to draw rectangles with different colors on a canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

The following code draws two rectangles:

```js
const demoCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas-demo').getContext('2d');

window.onload = function() {
  demoCanvas.fillStyle = 'red';
  demoCanvas.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
  demoCanvas.fill(); // first rectangle

  demoCanvas.fillStyle = 'blue';
  demoCanvas.rect(10, 110, 60, 60);
  demoCanvas.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-demo" width="300" height="300">
```

The output is two blue rectangles. I tried adding begin and close path as well, but the rectangles take only one color for some reason. In this case, it's blue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
const demoCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas-demo').getContext('2d');

window.onload = function() {

    demoCanvas.beginPath();
    demoCanvas.fillStyle = 'red';
    demoCanvas.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
    demoCanvas.fill();
    demoCanvas.closePath();

    demoCanvas.beginPath();
    demoCanvas.fillStyle = 'blue';
    demoCanvas.rect(10, 110, 60, 60);
    demoCanvas.fill();
    demoCanvas.closePath();
                
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-demo" width="300" height="300">
```

Hope you found this helpful, Cheers .